# Overlay navigation opacity change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I'm trying to get my menu display in overlay but with opacity change effect instead of height change. I'm having code I found here http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp
but I can't get this to work as I want.
I want to get rid of height 0%->100% change instead that I would like to change opacity 0->1 to create fadein effect.

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

When I changed it to this:

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.opacity = "1";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

And my css to this:

```
.overlay {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
overflow-y: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Overlay with menu shows on page load (not on button onclick) but when i close it I'm unable to re-open it.

Thats fiddle I've found http://jsfiddle.net/rubixx/ct3ve7pb/1/
and thats basically the same code I'm using but I want to get rid of height change, just opacity fadein overlay.

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot to change:

Instead of the initial `height: 0%` we use `display: none` to hide the overlay.

And instead of changing the height, we use fadeIn / fadeOut.

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ct3ve7pb/4/

```js
function openNav() {
    $("#myNav").fadeIn();
    $("#open-nav").hide();
}

function closeNav() {
    $("#myNav").fadeOut();
    $("#open-nav").show();
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: none;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px !important;
}
#open-nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 38px !important;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.open {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="open-nav" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>
```